# Trouble loading .csv into Jupyter

Tags: python, pandas, csv, jupyter

Hopefully this one isn't too much trouble. I'm working in a Jupyter Notebook and am trying to load in a csv file. The Excel spreadsheet lives in C:\Users\myusername, which is also the path of Jupyter, as determined by os.getcwd(). With the file in there, I still keep getting the FileNotFoundError message, and I'm not quite sure what I'm doing wrong (probably something dumb on my end). Any insights into how to load this file would be greatly appreciated!

```
FileNotFoundError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [2], in <cell line: 2>()
      1 import pandas as pd
----> 2 df = pd.read_csv("nsqip")

File ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\util\_decorators.py:311, in deprecate_nonkeyword_arguments.<locals>.decorate.<locals>.wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    305 if len(args) > num_allow_args:
    306     warnings.warn(
    307         msg.format(arguments=arguments),
    308         FutureWarning,
    309         stacklevel=stacklevel,
    310     )
--> 311 return func(*args, **kwargs)

File ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers\readers.py:680, in read_csv(filepath_or_buffer, sep, delimiter, header, names, index_col, usecols, squeeze, prefix, mangle_dupe_cols, dtype, engine, converters, true_values, false_values, skipinitialspace, skiprows, skipfooter, nrows, na_values, keep_default_na, na_filter, verbose, skip_blank_lines, parse_dates, infer_datetime_format, keep_date_col, date_parser, dayfirst, cache_dates, iterator, chunksize, compression, thousands, decimal, lineterminator, quotechar, quoting, doublequote, escapechar, comment, encoding, encoding_errors, dialect, error_bad_lines, warn_bad_lines, on_bad_lines, delim_whitespace, low_memory, memory_map, float_precision, storage_options)
    665 kwds_defaults = _refine_defaults_read(
    666     dialect,
    667     delimiter,
   (...)
    676     defaults={"delimiter": ","},
    677 )
    678 kwds.update(kwds_defaults)
--> 680 return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)

File ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers\readers.py:575, in _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
    572 _validate_names(kwds.get("names", None))
    574 # Create the parser.
--> 575 parser = TextFileReader(filepath_or_buffer, **kwds)
    577 if chunksize or iterator:
    578     return parser

File ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers\readers.py:933, in TextFileReader.__init__(self, f, engine, **kwds)
    930     self.options["has_index_names"] = kwds["has_index_names"]
    932 self.handles: IOHandles | None = None
--> 933 self._engine = self._make_engine(f, self.engine)

File ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers\readers.py:1217, in TextFileReader._make_engine(self, f, engine)
   1213     mode = "rb"
   1214 # error: No overload variant of "get_handle" matches argument types
   1215 # "Union[str, PathLike[str], ReadCsvBuffer[bytes], ReadCsvBuffer[str]]"
   1216 # , "str", "bool", "Any", "Any", "Any", "Any", "Any"
-> 1217 self.handles = get_handle(  # type: ignore[call-overload]
   1218     f,
   1219     mode,
   1220     encoding=self.options.get("encoding", None),
   1221     compression=self.options.get("compression", None),
   1222     memory_map=self.options.get("memory_map", False),
   1223     is_text=is_text,
   1224     errors=self.options.get("encoding_errors", "strict"),
   1225     storage_options=self.options.get("storage_options", None),
   1226 )
   1227 assert self.handles is not None
   1228 f = self.handles.handle

File ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\common.py:789, in get_handle(path_or_buf, mode, encoding, compression, memory_map, is_text, errors, storage_options)
    784 elif isinstance(handle, str):
    785     # Check whether the filename is to be opened in binary mode.
    786     # Binary mode does not support 'encoding' and 'newline'.
    787     if ioargs.encoding and "b" not in ioargs.mode:
    788         # Encoding
--> 789         handle = open(
    790             handle,
    791             ioargs.mode,
    792             encoding=ioargs.encoding,
    793             errors=errors,
    794             newline="",
    795         )
    796     else:
    797         # Binary mode
    798         handle = open(handle, ioargs.mode)

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'nsqip'
```

Comment: Add the .csv extension?

Comment: No dice. I've also tried running

df = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\myusername\nsqip.csv')

But I still get that error. The file is living in C:\Users\myusername, so I'm not quite sure why it's not recognizing it.

Comment: When you run the r prefix to a python string, it treats backslashes as a literal (raw) character. Normally, Python uses backslashes as escape characters. Also I would suggest reading file from relative path.

Comment: Have you looked at the Jupyter dashboard view (it usually lists the files present like the top part of 'Snap 1' [here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/jupyter-shows-nothing-no-files-no-filder/15402?u=fomightez)) for that directory and seen if that shows the file listed? I was helping someone on windows recently and Jupyter wasn't able to see the files there, see [here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/jupyter-shows-nothing-no-files-no-filder/15402?u=fomightez). Another idea to look into, is if you use OneDrive, often the files aren't where you think they are or get moved later.

Answer (score 0):

> No dice. I've also tried running df = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\myusername\nsqip.csv') But I still get that error. The file is living in C:\Users\myusername, so I'm not quite sure why it's not recognizing it.

When you run the r prefix to a python string, it treats backslashes as a literal (raw) character. Normally, Python uses backslashes as escape characters.

Reading files with relative paths is typically the way to go.  One solution would be to find the current path:

local_path = os.path.dirname(**file**)

After finding the local path, you can use the `.read_csv` method and make sure to add the .csv extension.